# Apache 2.4 VirtualHost not working throug through "NO-IP"

Tags: php, apache, ssl, virtualhost, noip

i have an Apache 2.4 server running on windows 7.
It has been running for many years, but now I'm trying to implement ssl.
In fact I did it, it works perfectly from the local network, but when I want to enter from an external network (through no-ip) I get the legend "404 page not found".
Here are my VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin sistemas@clinica25demayo.com.ar
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  ErrorLog logs/localhost.com-error.log
  CustomLog logs/localhost-access.log common    
  <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/certificados/cl25demayo.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/certificados/cl25demayo.key"
  ServerAdmin sistemas@clinica25demayo.com.ar
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  ErrorLog logs/localhost.com-error.log
  CustomLog logs/localhost-access.log common    
  <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible that it is, because my ssl certificates are provisional ?, I have generated them myself.

Comment: What happens if you try to connect without SSL?

Comment: with http: instead of https: works perfect

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that it is, because my ssl certificates are provisional

There's no such thing as a "provisional certificate" in x509.

> I have generated them myself

You mean a self-signed certificate? No. The certificate has no impact on different behaviour resulting from different client sub-nets.

> I get the legend "404 page not found"

Then you *must* be able to see the certificate and confirm it came from your server. You also have access to the server logs to see what traffic is arriving there.

I believe you are connecting to something other than your server - I can't tell you if that is because the DDNS service (ni-ip) is servicng up the wrong address or you've not configured the routing correctly or if there's something at the client network end configured to interfere with the traffic or if the traffic is landing on your webserver but it has some logic configured to return a 404 error to non-local clients.

You can easily verify this be looking at the certificate details passed via HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry, that's what i meant. "Self signed" certifcate. The no-ip works perfect if y use http:// instead of https://

The site is this:

http://cl25demayo.no-ip.org/cl25demayo

And if yo try:

https://cl25demayo.no-ip.org/cl25demayo.

What is striking is that the configuration for port 80 and for port 443 are identical.

Comment: I think that when i enter with "https", i'm been redirected to the Root, and /cl25demayo part is being ignored

Comment: If that's the case (unlikely) it will be in your logs.